# Constructor not binding arguments to class context

Tags: typescript

Here is my Greeter class:

```
// logger.ts
export class Logger {
  constructor() {}

  public log(msg : string) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}

// greeter.ts
import { Logger } from "./logger";

class Greeter {
  public foo: string;
  private l : Logger;
  constructor(l : Logger) {
    this.foo = "bar";
    this.l.log(this.foo);
  }
}

let g = new Greeter(new Logger());
console.log(g.foo);
```

This code compiles successfully. But when I run it I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
```

Whats happening?

**UPDATE:**
It fails on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you don't set the private field `l`
Try it like so

```
constructor(l : Logger) {
  this.foo = "bar";
  this.l = l;
  this.l.log(this.foo);
}
```

or (credits go to [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo))

```
constructor(private l : Logger) {
  this.foo = "bar";
  this.l.log(this.foo);
}
```

See JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2mkzmzgj/1/)

Comment: Or better, `constructor(private l: Logger)`.

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned to `this.l`. So the fixed code:

```
class Logger {
  constructor() {}

  public log(msg : string) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}

class Greeter {
  public foo: string;
  private l : Logger;
  constructor(l : Logger) {
    this.foo = "bar";
    this.l = l; // !!!!!This line is the fix!!!!!
    this.l.log(this.foo);
  }
}

let g = new Greeter(new Logger());
console.log(g.foo);
```